# How can I toggle between 2 different UICollectionViewFlowLayout instances?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

Been working on this for a few days now. I'm trying to allow customers of an app to switch between 2 display types when shopping.

Right now I'm using 2 `UICollectionView`'s with their own custom `UICollectionViewCell` and the switching between the two works fine but I'm finding that working with 2 different `UICollectionView`'s is becoming a pain. Certain things I've implemented for my main `UICollectionView` don't work properly in the alternative `UICollectionView`.

**This is how the display is changed. I use a `UISegmentedControl` with a custom method:**

[image]

```
- (void)displayTypeSegmentSelected
{
    _selectedDisplayTypeIndex = [_displayTypeControl selectedSegmentIndex];


    if (_selectedDisplayTypeIndex == 0) {
        NSLog(@"Single file item view selected");
        _fromCollectionView = _collectionView;
        _toCollectionView = _collectionView2;


    } else if (_selectedDisplayTypeIndex == 1) {
        NSLog(@"Grid style view selected");
        _fromCollectionView = _collectionView2;
        _toCollectionView = _collectionView;
    }

    [_fromCollectionView removeFromSuperview];

    [_toCollectionView setFrame:[_superView bounds]];
    [_superView addSubview:_toCollectionView];

}
```

**I've had two different suggestions via stackoverflow about a better way to do what I'm trying to do.**

1. Use 2 `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`'s and switch between them instead of 2 `UICollectionView`'s.
2. Return the appropriate custom `UICollectionViewCell` depending on what segment is selected.

I feel the first way would be better. I would need to make the interface builder `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` an IBOutlet because the connected `UICollectionView` wasn't created programmatically. Then I'd create the second `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` programmatically.

In my displayTypeSegmentSelected method I'd load one of the two `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`'s depending on the selected segment.

**Single File Display would look like this:**

[image]

**Grid Style Display would look like this:**

[image]

**Question:**

I think I have the right idea on the best way to go about doing what my original question asks and how to do it. However I'd profile an opinion and example from a more experience developer.
How would you do this and can you show me a clear example I can go and mess around with?

Kind Regards

Comment: at this point it might be worth it to put up a stripped down/barebone version of the code on github so anyone can play around with it... Good luck.

Comment: I agree with your decision that the first method, switching between layouts, is the way to go. There isn't a lot to do to accomplish that. It looks like you already have the two layouts built, just use setCollectionViewLayout:animated:completion: to switch between them in your segmented control's action method. Try to implement that, and come back with a more specific code-based question if you run into trouble.

Comment: @rdelmar, it literally took 5 minutes to set it up and it works perfectly. The animation is a bonus. The only issue I have now is the layout that I toggle to uses the cell of the originally layout which by default is much smaller than the cell I made for the single view layout. I get my single file view when I toggle and the cell is enlarged thanks to my layout settings (item inset 300x500) but because the other layouts cell is used the imageView remains small. What is the best way to fix this? I was thinking I could check for current layout in my cellForItemAtIndex but it's proving difficult.

Comment: Just use collectionView:layout:sizeForItemAtIndexPath:. The layout is passed in for you, so check which one it is, and return the size you want for that layout.

Comment: @rdelmar, this resizes the cell but not my image view that holds the items image. The image view just remains the same size.

Comment: You should have constraints between the image view and the cell, so the image view automatically expands and contracts with the cell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I did things in the end.

**Upon tapping of specific segmented control I changed the layout and reloaded the cells.**

```
- (void)displayTypeSegmentSelected
{
    _selectedDisplayTypeIndex = [_displayTypeControl selectedSegmentIndex];

    if (_selectedDisplayTypeIndex == 0) {
        NSLog(@"Single file item view selected");
        [_collectionView setCollectionViewLayout:_flowLayout2 animated:YES];
        [_collectionView reloadItemsAtIndexPaths:[_collectionView indexPathsForVisibleItems]];


    } else if (_selectedDisplayTypeIndex == 1) {
        NSLog(@"Grid style view selected");
        [_collectionView setCollectionViewLayout:_flowLayout animated:YES];
        [_collectionView reloadItemsAtIndexPaths:[_collectionView indexPathsForVisibleItems]];
    }

}
```

**In my `cellForItemAtIndexPath` depending on which layout was present on screen I loaded a specific custom cell with correct settings.**

```
-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath object:(PFObject *)object
{

        NSLog(@"collectionview 1 loaded");

        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
        VAGGarmentCell *cell = [_collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier: CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
        static NSString *CellIdentifier2 = @"Cell2";
        VAGGarmentCell2 *cell2 = [_collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier2 forIndexPath:indexPath];


    if ([[_collectionView collectionViewLayout] isEqual: _flowLayout]) {
        [[cell activityIndicator] startAnimating];

        PFFile *userImageFile = [object valueForKey:@"image"];
        [[cell imageView] setFile: userImageFile];
        [[cell imageView] loadInBackground];

        [[cell activityIndicator] stopAnimating];

        [[cell title] setText:[object valueForKey:@"title"]];
        [[cell price] setText:[NSString stringWithFormat: @"£%@ GBP", [object valueForKey:@"price"]]];
        return cell;

    } else if ([[_collectionView collectionViewLayout] isEqual: _flowLayout2]) {
        [[cell2 activityIndicator] startAnimating];

        PFFile *userImageFile = [object valueForKey:@"image"];
        [[cell2 imageView] setFile: userImageFile];
        [[cell2 imageView] loadInBackground];

        [[cell2 activityIndicator] stopAnimating];

        [[cell2 title] setText:[object valueForKey:@"title"]];
        [[cell2 price] setText:[NSString stringWithFormat: @"£%@ GBP", [object valueForKey:@"price"]]];
        return cell2;
    }

     return 0;

    //_addToFavouritesButton = [cell addFavouriteButton];

    [_addToFavouritesButton addTarget:_thisController action:@selector(addToFavouritesButtonTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
}
```

**In my viewDidLoad here's where I reference the nib file for the custom cell for single item display.**

```
// Grab cell nib file and give a reuse identifier
[_collectionView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"VAGGarmentCell2" bundle:nil] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Cell2"];
```

I get crashes but they're very hard to replicate, although every time I toggle between the different layouts my memory rises and rises. I'm guessing there's some old code that I need to remove. I'll sort this out tomorrow and check it out with instruments. However this is done and I can move on.

I may need to refactor the code where I repeat myself.

Comment: In the end crashes were nothing to do with this.

Comment: I really appreciate what you've done here and the code you've put up. I'm doing something similar, however my issue is the animations don't look that great and if I switch between the layouts quickly, all the cells disappear. Not great.

Answer (score 2):

I had some problems in the toggling animation of a collectionView display. Your solution also helped me.

Here is my result.

[image]

And here is the solution

Toggle action in ViewController

```
            if self.displayType == .grid {
                self.displayType = .table
            }else {
               self.displayType = .grid
            }

            // Only update item size here
            self.updateFlowLayout()

            self.collectionView.performBatchUpdates({

                self.collectionView.setCollectionViewLayout(self.flowLayout, animated: true)

            }, completion: { (finished) in

            })
```

I'm using one collectionViewCell.
Override the layoutSubviews of cell

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    if (self.bounds.width / self.bounds.height) > 1.4 {
        if self.displayType != .table {
            self.displayType = .table
        }
    }else {

        if self.displayType != .grid {
            self.displayType = .grid
        }
    }
}
```

And in displayType

```
var displayType : CastDisplayType = .grid {
        didSet {
            //Update constraints of subviews between cell
            updateLayout()
        }
    }
```

Hopes it could be helpful to some people.